# Get extra information from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I handle RecordNotFound error in my `application_controller.rb` as follow:

```
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :record_not_found

  private 

   def record_not_found
     flash[:error] = "Oops, we cannot find this record"
     redirect_to :back
   end
```

But I would like to get more information, such as class/table name of which record was not found.
How should I go about it?

Thank you.

Comment: Indeed, it's a pity that `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` instances carry along zero information with it (`class RecordNotFound < ActiveRecordError; end`, end of the story).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say for example,

```
begin
@user = User.find(params[:id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  flash[:notice] = "#No such record in User for id :: {params[:id]} on #{action_name}"
end
```

**UPDATE**

```
flash[:notice] = t('flash.recordnotfound',:class_name => self.class.name, :column_name => params[:id], :action_name => action_name)
```

Now in your `config/locales/en.yml` (this would help translate, refer to i18n [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html))

```
flash:
  recordnotfound:  "Sorry, no record od %{column_name} in class %{class_name} was found on you action %{action_name}"
```

If you do not want to use locales just put up this information in `flash[:notice]` itself.

**More dynamic ?**

Write a function and use the same flash [:notice] there. Wont hurt at all.

**want more data ?**

Heres a quick solution, i always `<%= params%>` in my views to know easily whats going and whats coming. You can then open your rails console and play along with different actions and so on.

```
user = User.new
user.save
user.errors.messages
```

All of this is good enough data, i think.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks ktk. This is great, but is there a way to generalize this to work for any class?

Comment: Thank you so much for such a terrific answer! The tip is very helpful too.

Answer (score 4):

I had some success with this:

```
# in app/controllers/application_controller.rb

rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :record_not_found

def record_not_found exception
  result = exception.message.match /Couldn't find ([\w]+) with 'id'=([\d]+)/
  # result[1] gives the name of the model
  # result[2] gives the primary key ID of the object that was not found
end
```

HTH

EDIT: Whitespace error removed at the end of the Regex.  Thanks to the commenters. :)

Comment: This doesn't work. `"Couldn't find EventType with 'id'=1".match(/Couldn't find ([\w]+) with 'id'=([\d]+) /` returns nothing.

Comment: You need to get rid of the whitespace at the end: `..with 'id'=([\d]+)[this whitespace]/`

Answer (score 3):

You can define a parameter in your rescue handler and exception will be passed there.

```
def record_not_found exception
  flash[:error] = "Oops, we cannot find this record"
  # extract info from exception

  redirect_to :back
end
```

If you can't get that info from the exception, you're out of luck (I think).

Comment: Thanks, Sergio. Could you please give me an example of extracting info from exception?

Comment: @AdamNYC: seems like you're [out of luck](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/RecordNotFound.html) after all. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I checked that before I asked :)

Comment: I was hoping this was possible as well.  Too bad.  Seems like a ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound should at least know what it was looking for that could not be found — even if it's something as non-end-user-friendly as "WHERE id = 27" or "{id: 27}".  That would help a lot in cases where you're looping through a bunch of records in a migration, for example, and trying to do where(name: name).first!.

Comment: Try this:  def record_not_found exception; result = exception.to_s.match  /Couldn't find ([\w]+) with 'id'=([\d]+) / ; # result[1] gives the model name; # result[2] gives the ID of the record that wasn't found; end

Answer (score 0):

Once you instantiate the model, you can check something like.

```
human = Human.new
human.errors
```

Check this in rails console so you could play with it and use it in the main controller.

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |exception|
    raise ActiveRecord, exception.message, exception.backtrace
end
```

**EDIT**
Make sure you the application controller extends the base.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 rescue_from Exception, :with => :record_not_found
  private 

   def record_not_found(e)
     flash[:error] = "Oops, we cannot find this record" + e.message
     redirect_to :back
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Claire. I got an error saying: exception class/object expected.